# Classes with no methods should be tested?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Should I test a class with no methods?

Let's say I have a configuration class that only has fields and I add a test that calls each field to see if they are there for example. But I think if one field is missing it would raise a compilation error in one of the calls or the field is not being used. So I think is rather pointless but I want some opinions.

Comment: The purpose of the unit test is to show stability at a unit level. If the unit itself has no variations, then I would say you could skip it.

In saying this however, if this class is used in other areas or affects some other big picture as a whole, you should be testing that big picture as an integration test instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the class has no methods, in somecases it is very important to add test cases in your test program. For example,

- If your class has **constant** types holding a specific value, then test cases are required to ensure those values are not modified.
- In case if a class has some **enum** declrations with out specifying values, then test cases are required to ensure order of variables is intact.
- If the **type** of declared variables needs to be strict (example: Many people stay on lighter side when it comes to double and float, but they cause very serious issues if altered especially in comparision operations), then test cases related to type check of variables should be added.
- In case if a class has an **array** holding list of messages in a order (relaying on array index for a specific message), then test cases are required to ensure no message is induced in between.